# Pandas : compute mean or std (standard deviation) over entire dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Here is my problem, I have a dataframe like this :

```
    Depr_1  Depr_2  Depr_3
S3  0   5   9
S2  4   11  8
S1  6   11  12
S5  0   4   11
S4  4   8   8
```

and I just want to calculate the mean over the full dataframe, as the following doesn't work :

```
df.mean()
```

Then I came up with :

```
df.mean().mean()
```

But this trick won't work for computing the standard deviation.  My final attempts were :

```
df.get_values().mean()
df.get_values().std()
```

Except that in the latter case, it uses mean() and std() function from numpy. It's not a problem for the mean, but it is for std, as the pandas function uses by default `ddof=1`, unlike the numpy one where `ddof=0`.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You could convert the dataframe to be a single column with `stack` (this changes the shape from 5x3 to 15x1) and then take the standard deviation:

```
df.stack().std()         # pandas default degrees of freedom is one
```

Alternatively, you can use `values` to convert from a pandas dataframe to a numpy array before taking the standard deviation:

```
df.values.std(ddof=1)    # numpy default degrees of freedom is zero
```

Unlike pandas, numpy will give the standard deviation of the entire array by default, so there is no need to reshape before taking the standard deviation.

A couple of additional notes:

- The numpy approach here is a bit faster than the pandas one, which is generally true when you have the option to accomplish the same thing with either numpy or pandas.  The speed difference will depend on the size of your data, but numpy was roughly 10x faster when I tested a few different sized dataframes on my laptop (numpy version 1.15.4 and pandas version 0.23.4).
- The numpy and pandas approaches here will not give exactly the same answers, but will be extremely close (identical at several digits of precision).  The discrepancy is due to slight differences in implementation behind the scenes that affect how the floating point values get rounded.

Answer (score 2):

## Use `axis=None`

Since pandas 2.0.0, you can use `axis=None` to compute mean over the entire dataframe.

```py
df.mean(axis=None)
```

For example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6]})
df.mean(axis=None)    # 3.5
```

In a future version, you can use `df.std(axis=None)` to compute for standard deviation over the entire dataframe as well but as of pandas 2.2.0, @JohnE's answer — `df.values.std(ddof=1)` is still the best way to compute it.

---

If there are NaN values that are causing problems, and if `stack()` is too slow for you, numpy has built-in functions that deal with it: prefix each standard function with `nan`.

```py
np.nanmean(df.values)   # mean with NaN ignored
np.nanstd(df.values)    # stdev with NaN ignored
np.nanmedian(df.values) # median with NaN ignored
```

Another approach is to just filter NaN values out:

```py
df.values[~np.isnan(df.values)].mean()     # mean
df.values[~np.isnan(df.values)].std()      # stdev
np.median(df.values[~np.isnan(df.values)]) # median
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, you can do it as:

```
df1 = df[1:].mean()
df2 = df[1:].std()
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,left_index = True , right_index =True)
```

It will take mean, std dev all the columns
and then  combine both.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# approach 1:
mean, std = df.stack().mean(), df.stack().std():

# approach 2:
mean, std = np.mean(df.mean().values), np.std(df.std().values):
```

First method aggregates the data across rows, effectively flattening the distribution and potentially masking the true variability within each column.

Second method, on the other hand, preserves the column-wise structure, allowing for a more accurate representation of the overall standard deviation.

In **general**, it's more *appropriate* to use the second method when analyzing the standard deviation of a DataFrame with multiple columns, as it provides a more meaningful and interpretable measure of dispersion.