# Standard deviation for DF, pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

for example I have a pandas DataFrame, which looks as:

```
a b c
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

I want to calculate the standard deviation for all values in this DF. The function `df.std()` get me back the values pro column.

Of course I can create the next code:

```
sd = []
sd.append(list(df['a']))
sd.append(list(df['b']))
sd.append(list(df['c']))
numpy.std(sd)
```

Is it possible to do this code simpler and use some pandas function for this DF?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas : compute mean or std (standard deviation) over entire dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25140998/pandas-compute-mean-or-std-standard-deviation-over-entire-dataframe)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`df.values` returns a NumPy array containing the values in `df`. You could then apply `np.std` to that array:

```
In [52]: np.std(sd)
Out[52]: 2.5819888974716112

In [53]: np.std(df.values)
Out[53]: 2.5819888974716112
```

Comment: Please see my answer below for what might be very unwelcome behavior: note that `numpy` and `pandas` standard deviation functions make **different** assumptions about degrees of freedom.  So various methods might not agree on "obvious" calculations.  Example below.

Comment: or `df.values.std()` since values() has converted the pandas dataframe into a numpy array so the method chaining is actually in numpy automatically

Answer (score 4):

An alternative, if you like the idea of "making a vector of all your values" and then taking its standard deviation:

```
df.stack().std()
```

**But big note here: please remember that pandas `std` functions assume a different denominator (degrees of freedom) than numpy `std` functions** so that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1, 10).reshape(3, 3), columns=list('abc'))
print np.std(df.values)
print df.stack().std()
print df.stack().std() * np.sqrt(8. / 9.)
```

yields:

```
2.58198889747
2.73861278753
2.58198889747
```

The middle number is different!  Not a typo!

Comment: Good point.  Note also that there is a `ddof` argument for both pandas and numpy `std` so you can make them equivalent.