# Compute standard deviation for cells of several DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

I have measurement data in similarly structured Pandas Dataframes and need to compute a standard deviation for each individual cell, not entire rows or columns.
I could do some looping, but the datasets are quite large, so this is not efficicent.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1],[2,2,2]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[0.9,0.8,0.7],[1.9,1.8,1.7]])
df3 = pd.DataFrame([[1.1,1.2,1.2],[2.1,2.2,2.2]])
```

The desired result would be

```
    0           1           2
0   0.08165     0.163299    0.244949
1   0.08165     0.163299    0.244949
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas : compute mean or std (standard deviation) over entire dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25140998/pandas-compute-mean-or-std-standard-deviation-over-entire-dataframe)

Comment: @APhillips if I read the question correctly, I think they want the element-wise std across dataframes, not the statistic for a single dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can use numpy.dstack to stack the values in a 3d array, then perform the st.dev. over the stacked axis

```
np.dstack((df1.values,df2.values,df3.values)).std(axis=2)

array([[0.08164966, 0.16329932, 0.20548047],
       [0.08164966, 0.16329932, 0.20548047]])
```

Note that the preferrred method for pushing the df values to an array in newer versions of pandas would be `to_numpy()` instead of `.values`

```
np.dstack((df1.to_numpy(),df2.to_numpy(),df3.to_numpy())).std(axis=2)
```

which gives the same result

Comment: Thanks a lot for this quick and exhaustive answer, this is it!