# How to create a dataframe that only selects rows that have value more than avg +/* standard deviation in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-datareader

This is the code that I have so far, but I am just not sure if I should just join the dataframes after figuring out the standard deviation and average. Where I am currently stuck is selecting the rows that have value more or less than avg +/1 std. I just do not know how I would be able to iterate through each column and do this? I thought about a for loop, but wasn't exactly sure how to go about it.

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime as date

fromDate ="2014-01-02"
toDate = "2016-01-02"

dfSixMo =  web.DataReader('DGS6MO','fred',fromDate,toDate)

dfOneYear = web.DataReader('DGS1','fred',fromDate,toDate)

dfFiveYear = web.DataReader('DGS5','fred',fromDate,toDate)

dfTenYear = web.DataReader('DGS10','fred',fromDate,toDate)

dfJoin1 = dfSixMo.join(dfOneYear,how = 'inner')
dfJoin2 = dfFiveYear.join(dfTenYear,how='inner')
dfFinal = dfJoin1.join(dfJoin2,how='inner')
print(dfFinal)

mean = dfFinal.mean()
print('\nMean:')
print(mean)

StDev = dfFinal.std()
print('\n Standard Deviation:')
print(StDev)
```

Comment: can you share sample data please?

Comment: If you want to standard deviation for the entire DataFrame, you can give `df.stack().std()`. Similarly, `df.stack().mean()`

Comment: The alternate is to use numpy option. `df.values.std(ddof=1)`. More on this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25140998/pandas-compute-mean-or-std-standard-deviation-over-entire-dataframe)

Answer (score 2):

IIUC this is what you want:

```
#setup
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,(3,3)), columns = list('abc'))
#   a  b  c
#0  3  2  8
#1  0  6  7
#2  8  3  9

mean = df.mean()
std = df.std()

df[((mean-std < df) & (df< mean+std)).all(1)]
#   a  b  c
#0  3  2  8
```